# General Solution of $y''y + (y')^2 - y = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following non linear ODE and I'm struggling to find the solution.

Naturally, I thought to let $w=y'$ so that $y''=w'=w*dw/dy$ but i keep getting lost in the calculation.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: If $w=y'$ then $w'=y''\neq ww'$

Comment: Sorry I made a typo in the question i will change that now. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if it helps but your equation is equivalent to $(y'y)' -y = 0$.

Comment: Thanks Zub Zub, I actually did get to your form of the equation but I wasn't sure if it would help me. Think the typo is sorted now!

Answer (score 2):

An obvious solution is $y=0$. We will suppose in the following $y\ne 0$.  As the equation does not explicitly depend on $x$, it is convenient to pose $y'(x)=f(y)$, then 
\begin{equation}
 y''(x)=\frac{d^2y(x)}{dx^2}=\frac{dy'(x)}{dx}=\frac{df(y)}{dy}\frac{dy(x)}{dx} =\frac{df(y)}{dy}f(y)
\end{equation}  to obtain
\begin{equation}
 y\frac{df(y)}{dy}f(y)+f^2(y)-y=0
\end{equation} 
or
\begin{equation}
 f(y)\frac{d}{dy}(f(y)y)-y=0
\end{equation} 
Posing now $f(y)=g(y)/y$, one obtains
\begin{equation}
 g(y)\frac{dg(y)}{dy}=y^2
\end{equation} 
which is directly integrated:
\begin{equation}
 g(y)=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}y^3+C}
\end{equation}
Thus
\begin{equation}
 y'(x)=\pm \frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}y^3+C}}{y}
\end{equation} 
Variables are separated, leading to
\begin{equation}
 \pm x+D=\int\frac{ydy}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}y^3+C}}
\end{equation}

Comment: In your first equation shouldn't the RHS read $f(y)f'(y)$?

Comment: You are right, sorry, I correct it

Comment: Also in your 3rd equation, I don't see how the $f(y)$ has ended up there multiplying the term being differentiated on the LHS...?

Comment: Simply $f(y)\left( yf'(y)+f(y)\right)=f(y)\left(yf(y)\right)'$.

Comment: But the $'$ is with respect to x in this right, so shouldn't $(yf(y))' = yf'(y)dy/dx + f(y)dy/dx = yf(y)f'(y) + f^2(y) = f(y)(yf'(y)+f(y))$ which you have then multiplied by f(y) in writing $f(y)(yf(y))'$ so we do not have an equality?

Comment: I edited the the answer to give more precise notations. $f$ is considered as a function of $y$. Its derivatives are taken with respect to this variable. This appears clearly in the first equation.

Comment: This is a standard approach when the variable does not explicitly appears in the equation. See for example the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2404530/solving-the-differential-equation-y-y21/2404571#2404571).

Comment: Thanks you've made this a lot clearer to me now!